# How do I display UIImageView array in background thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, uiimageview

I'm having the hardest time trying to find a way to run this method in the background as to not interrupt the UI.

I was trying to either set the UIImageView *ImgArray to an NSArray or NSMutableArray that could be used with GCD somehow or some way to return the UIScrollView or UIImageArray.  I've been coming to a bunch of dead ends.

**EDIT:**

*I had the wrong method before*

```
 -(void)getSlideshow{
    //This populates string array from a URL
    //[self populateStringArray];
    NSString *prefix = @"http://newsongbismarck.com/images/announcements/";
    NSString *suffix = @".jpg";

    //NSUInteger count = [imageStringArray count];
    //get this from the website for now
    int number = (int)[imageStringArray count];
    int PageCount = number;

    //Setup scroll view
    UIScrollView *Scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 265, 320, 200)];
    Scroller.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    Scroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
    Scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(PageCount * Scroller.bounds.size.width, Scroller.bounds.size.height);

    //Setup Each View Size
    CGRect ViewSize = Scroller.bounds;

    int x = PageCount;
    int numb = 0;

    UIImageView *ImgArray[PageCount];

    //This loop adds the Images to a UIImageView within a UIScrollView
    while(x!=0){
        ImgArray[numb] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:ViewSize];
        [ImgArray[numb] setImage:[self getSlideshowImages:[[prefix stringByAppendingString:imageStringArray[numb]]stringByAppendingString:suffix]]];

        //I haven't been able to make this work with dispatch_async main thread
        [Scroller addSubview:ImgArray[numb]];

        //Offset View Size
        ViewSize = CGRectOffset(ViewSize, Scroller.bounds.size.width, 0);

        x--;
        numb++;
    }



    CGRect newViewSize = Scroller.bounds;
    int NumberOfImages = 21;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<NumberOfImages;i++){

        if(i == 0){
            //Setup first picture
            UIImageView *ImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:newViewSize];
            NSString *FilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page_%d.png", i];
            [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:FilePath]];
            [Scroller addSubview:ImgView];
        }else{
            //Setup the rest of the pictures
            newViewSize = CGRectOffset(ViewSize, Scroller.bounds.size.width, 0);
            UIImageView *ImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:newViewSize];
            NSString *FilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page_%d.png", i];
            [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:FilePath]];
            [Scroller addSubview:ImgView];
        }
    }

    //This adds the Scroller
    [self.view addSubview:Scroller];


}
```

**EDIT2:**

Here is my attempt at GCD, I wasn't sure where to add or set the scroller view or the UIImageView... the AFNetworking looks promising.

The code is still pretty messy.

```
-(void)showSlideShow{
[activity startAnimating];
[self populateStringArray];

NSString *URLString = @"http://newsongbismarck.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];

if(url){
dispatch_queue_t slideQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Slide Show Queue",NULL);

dispatch_async(slideQueue, ^{

    // Perform long running process
    //[self populateStringArray];
    NSLog(@"Start background");
    NSString *prefix = @"http://newsongbismarck.com/images/announcements/";
    NSString *suffix = @".jpg";

    //NSUInteger count = [imageStringArray count];
    //get this from the website for now
    int number = (int)[imageStringArray count];
    int PageCount = number;

    //Setup scroll view
    UIScrollView *Scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 265, 320, 200)];
    Scroller.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    Scroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
    Scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(PageCount * Scroller.bounds.size.width, Scroller.bounds.size.height);

    //Setup Each View Size
    CGRect ViewSize = Scroller.bounds;

    int x = PageCount;
    int numb = 0;

    UIImageView *ImgArray[PageCount];

    while(x!=0){
        ImgArray[numb] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:ViewSize];
        [ImgArray[numb] setImage:[self getSlideshowImages:[[prefix stringByAppendingString:imageStringArray[numb]]stringByAppendingString:suffix]]];
        //[Scroller addSubview:ImgArray[numb]];

        //Offset View Size
        ViewSize = CGRectOffset(ViewSize, Scroller.bounds.size.width, 0);

        x--;
        numb++;
    }

    CGRect newViewSize = Scroller.bounds;
    int NumberOfImages = 21;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<NumberOfImages;i++){

        if(i == 0){
            //Setup first picture
            UIImageView *ImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:newViewSize];
            NSString *FilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page_%d.png", i];
            [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:FilePath]];
            [Scroller addSubview:ImgView];
        }else{
            //Setup the rest of the pictures
            newViewSize = CGRectOffset(ViewSize, Scroller.bounds.size.width, 0);
            UIImageView *ImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:newViewSize];
            NSString *FilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page_%d.png", i];
            [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:FilePath]];
            [Scroller addSubview:ImgView];
        }
    }


    NSLog(@"End of background tasks");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Update the UI
        NSLog(@"Start main thread");
        int x = PageCount;
        int numb = 0;

        UIImageView *ImgArray[PageCount];

        while(x!=0){

            [Scroller addSubview:ImgArray[numb]];

            x--;
            numb++;
        }

        [self.view addSubview:Scroller];

        [activity stopAnimating];
    });
});

}else{
    loadLabel.text = @"Error - could not load images";

    [activity stopAnimating];
}
}
```

Comment: did you try dispatch_async?

Comment: Yes @MihaiAndreiRustiuc, I have tried dispatch_async, but I cannot get it to update the UI, I put the [self.view addSubview:Scroller] in the main thread... I also noticed I put the wrong method in the description. I have changed it now, so it might make more sense.

Comment: I suggest trying AFNetworking's UIImageView category for setting an image to a UIImageView from URL. It has an async block, thus you can place the addSubview: call at the end of the block (so when it finished downloading the image). Moreover, I have noticed a bit of ObjC style misuse, I suggest reading this style guide: https://github.com/macoscope/objc-style-guide to make your code more readable.

Comment: Would you mind posting your attempt with GCD?

Answer (score 0):

Not that what you're asking is impossible, but have you considered a simpler approach?

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
imageView.animationImages = @[image1, image2, image3];
imageView.animationDuration = imageView.animationImages.count * 1.0f;   // 1 second per image
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;     // 0 means loop forever
[imageView startAnimating];
```

Comment: I was missing stuff in the first method I posted, I changed it now.